# Retrieving the classification layer prediction produces the same result all the time

Tags: python, tensorflow

The data is being fed into the model using Dataset iterators:

```
self.validate_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(\
    (features.astype(float), labels) ).batch(self.batch_size)
...
self.validate_init_op = \
    iterator.make_initializer(self.validate_data)
...
self.sess.run(self.validate_init_op)
```

The last layer of the model is producing classification result:

```
drop2 = tf.layers.dropout(hidden2,rate=0.5)
self.logits = tf.layers.dense(drop2,len(self.label_names),name="logits")
```

The validation loop retrieves `self.logits` as `predictions` so that I could manually compare predictions with the labels. `predictions` is a 2D array of size `(self.batch_size,self.label_names)`, which is 100x10 in this run. Each row is an array of the label probabilities. Likewise, the rows of `self.validate_labels` are `eye`s of the labels.

```
self.sess.run(self.validate_init_op)
for iteration in range(n_validate_batches):
    summary, predictions, batch_loss = self.sess.run(\
        [self.merged_summary, self.logits, self.loss])
    ...
    for r in range(predictions.shape[0]):
        prediced_eye = predictions[r,:]
        label_index = iteration * self.batch_size + r
        best_guess = np.argmax(prediced_eye)
        assert(best_guess < self.validate_labels.shape[1])
        if epo==(epochs-1) and iteration<1 and r < 3:
            print("DEBUG: best_guess = {}, predictions[{}] = {}". \
                format(best_guess, r, str(prediced_eye)))
            print("DEBUG: guessed = {}, validate_labels[{}] = {}". \
                format(self.validate_labels[label_index,best_guess],
                    label_index, self.validate_labels[label_index]))
```

In the above loop I'm printing prediction for several data points. To my surprise, the prediction probability arrays were identical:

```
DEBUG: best_guess = 5, predictions[0] = [0.07977642 0.02335115 0.07917383 0.03262045 0.06117218 0.09661281
 0.0569936  0.06503091 0.07465875 0.04835918]
DEBUG: guessed = 0.0, validate_labels[0] = [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0.]

DEBUG: best_guess = 5, predictions[1] = [0.07977642 0.02335115 0.07917383 0.03262045 0.06117218 0.09661281
 0.0569936  0.06503091 0.07465875 0.04835918]
DEBUG: guessed = 0.0, validate_labels[1] = [0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]

DEBUG: best_guess = 5, predictions[2] = [0.07977642 0.02335115 0.07917383 0.03262045 0.06117218 0.09661281
 0.0569936  0.06503091 0.07465875 0.04835918]
DEBUG: guessed = 0.0, validate_labels[2] = [0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
```

It looks like `predictions` didn't get updated between datapoints, or `self.logits` was executed only once, or something else caused all the prediction within each batch as well as between batches to be identical.

Could you suggest what could be the problem here?

---

Per Anand's advice I'm also printing the inputs now. Here's the testing code; the difference is that I'm also printing Sha1 code of the input:

```
self.prepare_test_data(self.batch_size)
self.test_init_op = self.iterator.make_initializer(self.test_data)
n_test_batches = len(self.test_labels) // self.batch_size

print("\nTesting the model.")
self.sess.run(self.test_init_op)

guessed = 0
for iteration in range(n_test_batches):
  summary, inputs, predictions = self.sess.run(\
        [self.merged_summary, self.flat_features, self.logits])
  for r in range(predictions.shape[0]):
    predicted_eye = predictions[r,:]
    label_index = iteration * self.batch_size + r
    best_guess = np.argmax(predicted_eye)
    assert(best_guess < self.test_labels.shape[1])
    if (iteration%50)==0 and r<3:
      m = hashlib.sha1()
      m.update(inputs[r,:])
      print("\nDEBUG: batch {} row = {}: inputs hash = {}". \
                format(iteration, r, str(m.digest())))
      print("row {}: argmax = {}, predictions = {}". \
                format(r, best_guess, str(predicted_eye)))
      print("label {}: eye[{}] = {}, test_labels = {}". \
                format(label_index, best_guess,
                    self.test_labels[label_index,best_guess],
                    self.test_labels[label_index]))
  guessed += self.test_labels[label_index,best_guess] / self.batch_size

print("Test top-1 rate =", guessed/n_test_batches)
```

And here's a portion of the output:

```
DEBUG: batch 50 row = 0: inputs hash = b';\xc9\xf1\xc7\xa3\x183\xd2\xf9\xb4\xa3\xee\x19Q0\xcd\xda;\x8f\x0e'
row 0: argmax = 8, predictions = [ 0.06992176 -0.00317043  0.05659114  0.02182345  0.03729291  0.06833207
  0.0450546   0.0401533   0.07006571  0.00714686]
label 5000: eye[8] = 0.0, test_labels = [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]

DEBUG: batch 50 row = 1: inputs hash = b'\xcf\xc8P\x8fC\x85C\xa2E\x97\xe5be [\x85 \xd65\xab'
row 1: argmax = 8, predictions = [ 0.06992176 -0.00317043  0.05659114  0.02182345  0.03729291  0.06833207
  0.0450546   0.0401533   0.07006571  0.00714686]
label 5001: eye[8] = 0.0, test_labels = [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0.]

DEBUG: batch 50 row = 2: inputs hash = b"'\x8c\x03\xab'\x06\x0c\xb2S,2\x95_\x10\xb0\xe1\n\x94\xbb\xa8"
row 2: argmax = 8, predictions = [ 0.06992176 -0.00317043  0.05659114  0.02182345  0.03729291  0.06833207
  0.0450546   0.0401533   0.07006571  0.00714686]
label 5002: eye[8] = 1.0, test_labels = [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0.]
Test top-1 rate = 0.0009
```

Notice that the input hashes are all different, but the predictions are identical.

Comment: What are your inputs?

Comment: @rvinas, My inputs are [cifar-10](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~kriz/cifar.html), which are 40000 32x32x3 images in 10 categories. I use 10% of that for validation.

Comment: How do you feed your inputs into the network? Shouldn't you be using the `feed_dict` argument in `self.sess.run`?

Comment: @rvinas, I used `tf.data.Dataset` iterators instead; added that to the top of the question.

Comment: Run your code for 3 to 5 inputs, store those inputs in a list and compare them, I had a similar problem and it was because of the way I was yielding the data, maybe it's worth a look.

Comment: @anand_v.singh: just added input hashes to the output. The inputs are all different, but the predictions are identical.